# Auto layout is off

Tags: ios, autolayout

I've turned off autolayout in Xcode to worry less about constraints. Once my content is set on the story board, the position is always changed when I build my app. Any ideas on how to fix this? I thought the placement on whatever you set on the story board stayed the same (from my comprehension). Any idea helps!

Comment: Simple solution: use autolayout.

Comment: Its recommended to use auto layout. But if need to set position without auto layout then you can set the values as given in the following link: https://github.com/Kadasiddha/dailPad

Check the view controller file in the above link.
 If the position issue is occurring for only few screens then make different storyboard for these screen which doesn't have auto layout and different storyboard with auto layout.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Autolayout otherwise you will see placement issues at run time. I would recommend you to watch WWDC videos or apple documentation.

There are three main approaches to laying out a user interface.

1. You can programmatically lay out the user interface.
2. You can use autoresizing masks to automate some of the responses to external change
3. Or you can use Auto Layout.

Traditionally, apps laid out their user interface by programmatically setting the frame for each view in a view hierarchy. The frame defined the view’s origin, height, and width in the superview’s coordinate system.

To lay out your user interface, you had to calculate the size and position for every view in your view hierarchy. Then, if a change occurred, you had to recalculate the frame for all the effected views.

Other option is AutoResizingMask but you cannot use it for complex user interfaces.

Auto Layout represents an entirely new paradigm. Instead of thinking about a view’s frame, you think about its relationships.

I would highly recommend you to go through the following documentation -
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH7-SW1